# Laravel 4, jQuery .ajax, No post input received

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I must be missing something, didn't think this would have been a issue.

I have a login form that has no connection to laravel form, although its on the same domain, and a POST route with laravel at "login".

I can change it to GET and everything works, but I would like to use POST.

**/online/index.html**

```
$("#login").click(function(e){
    console.log( $("#loginForm").serialize() );
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "../login/",
      type: "POST",
      data: { test : "someuser" },
      dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function( data ) {
      console.log("Complete");
      console.log(data);
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      console.log("Failed");
      console.log(textStatus);
    });
});
```

**Route::post('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@doLogin'));**
( which is below /online/ )

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function doLogin(){

        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');

        return Response::json(Input::all());

    }
}
```

In the javascript console, when you press login, it shows...

```
Complete
[]
```

When it should say something like this...

```
Complete
[ test => "someuser" ]
```

Using Laravel 4, jQuery 1.8.3. Any ideas would be great... Thanks!

Comment: if you're using chrome / safari, open the network tab and check that the post data is being sent as you're intending

Comment: It is sent as intended. If I change the ajax call to get, everything works as expected. Its just when its a POST call that the values don't get passed to laravel.

Comment: Does `Input::json()` work? If it does, you need to change your AJAX request's content-type header to `application/json`.

Comment: You have configured a route of "post" type in your routes file?

Comment: Route::post('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@doLogin'));

Comment: Input::json() doesn't return anything either. Response::json() changes the header type to JSON.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that it requests "login" twice, once as POST, then once as GET, after the POST recieved a 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed the trailing slash in the Ajax request URL and everything worked as planned.